# Find Row with Max zero

Tags: java, matrix

To find the row  with max zero Matrix will have either 0 or 1 in sorted manner.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[][] inp=new int[][]{
                            {0,0,0,1,1},
                            {0,1,1,1,1},
                            {0,0,1,1,1},
                            {0,0,0,0,1}
                            };
    int j=0,rownum=0;       
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        while(j<=4&&inp[i][j]!=1){
            rownum=i;
            j++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Row "+(rownum+1)+" has Max zero");

}
```

Complexity of the  above program is \$O(m+n)\$ where \$m\$ is row size and \$n\$ is column size.

If any better approach is there then please post in this

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can do something to reduce `Complexity` in any traditional way. You have to traverse all `array elements` in order to find the row with the `max element`,so `m x n` iterations will give you `O(m+n) Complexity`.

Comment: reversing is additional operation.  I have already written program with O(m+n). I wanted to find any other way or approach with minimal complexity than O(m+n)